# Pandas accumulate data for linear regression

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I try to adjust my data so total_gross per day is accumulated. E.g.

```
`Created` `total_gross`  `total_gross_accumulated`
Day 1     100            100
Day 2     100            200
Day 3     100            300
Day 4     100            400
```

Any idea, how I have to change my code to have **total_gross_accumulated** available?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ym8SX2wSFUtHI5bnZd89BCtdHr-IKyK3cqduhsEkdT4/edit?usp=sharing) is my data.

my code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv', usecols=['created', 'total_gross'])
    df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    return df.set_index('created').resample('D').sum().fillna(0)

event_data = load_event_data()

X = event_data.index
y = event_data.total_gross

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*List comprehension is the most pythonic way to do this.*

**SHORT answer:**

This should give you the new column that you want:

```
n = event_data.shape[0]

# skip line 0 and start by accumulating from 1 until the end
total_gross_accumulated =[event_data['total_gross'][:i].sum() for i in range(1,n+1)]

# add the new variable in the initial pandas dataframe
event_data['total_gross_accumulated'] = total_gross_accumulated
```

**OR faster**

```
event_data['total_gross_accumulated'] = event_data['total_gross'].cumsum()
```

---

**LONG answer:**
Full code using your data:

```
import pandas as pd

def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv', usecols=['created', 'total_gross'])
    df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)

    return df.set_index('created').resample('D').sum().fillna(0)


event_data = load_event_data()

n = event_data.shape[0]

# skip line 0 and start by accumulating from 1 until the end
total_gross_accumulated =[event_data['total_gross'][:i].sum() for i in range(1,n+1)]

# add the new variable in the initial pandas dataframe
event_data['total_gross_accumulated'] = total_gross_accumulated
```

---

Results:

```
event_data.head(6)

#            total_gross  total_gross_accumulated
#created
#2019-03-01      3481810                  3481810
#2019-03-02         4690                  3486500
#2019-03-03            0                  3486500
#2019-03-04            0                  3486500
#2019-03-05            0                  3486500
#2019-03-06            0                  3486500


X = event_data.index
y = event_data.total_gross_accumulated

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that works. Thank you serafeim. I just learned about that command here: `event_data['cumsum'] = event_data['total_gross'].cumsum()` And acutally it works with just one line. Anything, that speaks against this approach?

Comment: yes, i have included this in my answer. both are equivalent. Your approach seems fine. consider upvoting my answer. cheers